# Doctrine entity Extending functional

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entity, extend

I use doctrine with symfony.
I have entity **User**.

I want to have different **classes** for this **User Entity**

- `UserApi` (*`->toArray()` with some data*),
- `UserSite` (*`->toArray()` with another data*)
- `UserAdmin` (*other specific methods*),

this models have same data (properties), but different functionality

How can i get that?

---

i don't need different models.

i want have ONE model, and several representations.

Answer (score 2):

Use [single-table-inheritance](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#single-table-inheritance).

Models will be seperated by a discriminator column.

Comment: i don't need different models.
i want have ONE model, and several representations.

ps updated my q

Comment: @user1272025 this is the way to have different classes for this User Entity, but perhaps you just want to add three different methods that get called in different contexts

Comment: i want to store business logic separate.
put all code in one entity class doesn't look pretty solution

Comment: Ok, then my first Idea would be to use a decorator pattern within special repository methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `FOS/user-bundle` you can grant users roles, you can create your own or use the pre-defined (Admin is a predefined).
https://symfony.com/doc/2.0.x/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html

If you really want to to this yourself one way you can have one model but different instantiations is you set your user to have a bool for whether it has a role and then make a new object when requested based on roles:

```php
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\UserRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="users")
 */
class User
{

    /** @Column(name="`isApiUser`", type="boolean") */
    private $isApiUser;

    /** @Column(name="`isSiteUser`", type="boolean") */
    private $isSiteUser;

    /** @Column(name="`isAdminUser`", type="boolean") */
    private $isAdminUser;

    //....
    public function getApiUser(): ?ApiUser
    {
        return $this->isApiUser() ? new ApiUser($this) : null;
    }

    public function getSiteUser(): SiteUser
    {
        return $this->isSiteUser() ? new SiteUser($this) : null;
    }

    public function getAdminUser(): ApiUser
    {
        return $this->isAdminUser() ? new AdminUser($this);
    }
    //....

}
```

Then have have each user Object do something like:

```
class ApiUser
{
    private $userName;

    public function __construct(User $user)
    {
        $this->userName = $user->getUserName();
        // Continue for whatever logic you want
    }

}
```

Do the same for each of the user types.

Then when you want to use it in your controller (or whereever)

```
class SomeController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction()
    {

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class);

        $user = $product = $repository->findOneBy([
            'userName' => 'UserName', 
            'isApiUser' => true
        ]);
        $apiUser = $this->getApiUser();
    }

}
```